# Why does this nicescroll.js function only work in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, nicescroll

When I add some jQuery code to my website, it working in chrome but not in Firefox, IE, or Microsoft Edge. When I try to rewrite the code again in a new project file from scratch, I found it works in all browsers.

The problem is with the `nicescroll.js` file; it works with Chrome and not in Firefox or other browsers, but I don't know the reason; I've used the file in other projects in the past without issue. Why wouldn't the below code work in Firefox or Edge?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").niceScroll({
      cursorcolor:"#229ecf",
      cursorwidth:"7px"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are using version: "3.7.6" of nice Scroll

It works seamlessly with Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.

You can get the latest version here[Nicescroll on Github](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll)

Comment: i use this version and i just download last version and use it but still not working in mozilla firefox ..

Comment: Can you share  snippets of your html and the directory structure of your project.Weill try to recreate this problem

Comment: i don't understand what you mean ..you need my html project file or what ..?